# Show captcha in Django only when the user enters wrong password for 3 times?

Tags: django, recaptcha

I have a login view like this:

```
def login_backend(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        state = "Username or Password Incorrect!"
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/overview/')
        else:
            captcha = CaptchaField()
            return render_to_response('login_backend.html', {'state':state, 
                                                       'captcha':captcha }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        return render_to_response('login_backend.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Now, if the user is wrong for more than one time, captcha is shown. However, I want to show captcha only when the user enters wrong password for more than 3 times. I think I can keep the track of the user attempt and if `attempt > 3`, I can show the captcha but I don't know how to implement it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `attempt` variable in session data this way:

```
request.session['attempt'] = 1
```

and use session as a regular dict, which means using tools such as

```
if 'attempt' in request.session:
```

Comment: If the robot would reset its session, the attempt would always be null, so a robot would never need to fill in the captcha. I think the only way is to store the IPs.